# Excel: find proper value with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two small tables.

Table 1 (columns):
Customer ID, Sales by year, Discount

Table 2 (columns):
Customer ID, From, To, Discount

The idea is that from Table 2 I need to get information about discount basing on Sales by year column for proper customer. Table 2 contains ranges of sales.
Let say that from 0 to 10 000 your discount is 0 then from 10 001 to 20 000 is 2% etc.
So I just created vlookup(Sales by year, From:Discount,3,True) and by this way I get proper discount.

The problem is that I need to apply different data range in vlookup From:Discount because it does not include here customer ID.

Do you know any solution where I could just basing on Customer ID and Sales by year get proper Discount amount from Table 2?

Comment: Do you have Excel O365?  If so, this gets *very* easy to solve, and if you don't, it can still be solved.

Comment: @MaxR could you tell me both solutions, please?